# How to get more accurate Geolocation in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an app that has been developed which needs to give accurate geolocation information when I request it.

So far, it gives information correctly only about 40% of the time. Is there anything that I am missing?

Below is the function that is written to fetch it.

```
 initMap(){

let optionsGPS = {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(optionsGPS).then((position) => {

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  let mylat =  position.coords.latitude;
  let mylng =  position.coords.longitude;
  let mylatlng = {
    'lat': mylat,
    'lng': mylng
  };

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  this.addMarker(mylatlng, 'You', 'you');

  for (let provider of this.myProviders) {

    this.addMarker(provider, provider['name'], provider['type']);
  }
});
```

}

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try with the **[cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy)**

Comment: You can get the location sth about five times then average them.